# error with VBa writing binary file appending with existing file

Tags: vba, excel, file, binary, append

Please help ,this is my code and i don't know how to do in vba to append another element with existing file:

```
Type TestType
  intVar As Integer
  strVar As String
  predefinedSizeArray(10) As Long
End Type

Public Sub WriteBinary()
   Dim fileName As String, fileNo As Integer, testVar As TestType
   fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.bin"

    testVar.intVar = 4
    testVar.strVar = "Hello!"
    testVar.predefinedSizeArray(0) = 15

    fileNo = FreeFile
    Open fileName For Binary Lock Read Write As #fileNo
      Seek #fileNo, LOF(fileNo)
     Put #fileNo, , testVar
    Close #fileNo
End Sub


 Public Sub ReadBinary()
    Dim fileName As String, fileNo As Integer, testVar As TestType
    fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.bin"

   fileNo = FreeFile
   Open fileName For Binary Lock Read As #fileNo
   Do While Not EOF(fileNo)
      Get #fileNo, , testVar
      Debug.Print testVar.intVar 'Print the Integer
      Debug.Print testVar.strVar 'Print the String
      Debug.Print testVar.predefinedSizeArray(0) 'Print the String
      Debug.Print TypeName(testVar.predefinedSizeArray)
  Loop
  Close #fileNo
 End Sub
```

How to do that,how to write and read to Vba binary file without removing ?
Please help

Answer (score 1):

To `Append` you need to `Seek #fileNo, LOF(fileNo) + 1`; the `+ 1` moves you past the end of the file.

Hope that helps

Comment: I totally overlooked the missing increment in the `Seek` line (+1).  It should be noted though that `Get` actually leaves the file pointer at the correct place to read the *next* record - It's only need in your sample because you're going backward.

Comment: It works but i have:

  When i add two element:
      
     4
     "Hello!"
    15

     4

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to code ReadBinary:

```
Public Sub ReadBinary()
    Dim fileName As String, fileNo As Integer, testVar As TestType
    fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.bin"

    fileNo = FreeFile
    Open fileName For Binary Lock Read As #fileNo
    Do
        Get #fileNo, , testVar
        If EOF(fileNo) Then Exit Do
        Debug.Print testVar.intVar 'Print the Integer
        Debug.Print testVar.strVar 'Print the String
        Debug.Print testVar.predefinedSizeArray(0) 'Print the String
        Debug.Print TypeName(testVar.predefinedSizeArray)
    Loop
    Close #fileNo
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.